# Проблема с регистрацией. Данные из кода не передаются в бд. В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Код регистрации -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
     rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if($result){
        $smsg = "Регистрация прошла успешно";
    } else {
        $fsmsg = "Ошибка";
    }
}
?>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
            <h2>Registration</h2>
            <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?></div><?php }?>
            <?php if(isset($fsmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fsmsg; ?></div><?php }?>
            <input class="form-control" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
            <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Строка подключения -

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'practice');
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вот у вас написано ошибка я сомневаюсь, что у кого-то есть время подключать ваш шедевр и смотреть какая ошибка. но вот функция mysqli_error может вам подсказать какая именно ошибка произошла и уже учитывая эту информацию вы сможете сориентироваться что у вас там произошло

Comment: binliz я описал действующую ошибку пытался найти ответы но везде по разному где нужно поменять строку в конфиге на $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie' что у меня и было потом искал проблему в актив (строке) но и там ничего не нашел.

Comment: что-то вы там не так описали нам, в скрине пишет, что у вас в строке 8 файла connect.php ошибка, что невозможно т.к. у вас 4 строки, и забудьте закрывающий тег ?> - часто это причина появления ошибок в скриптах. И по коду ошибки у вас нет подключения к бд, что-то не так с кредами или самой базой.

Comment: На скриншоте как бы вполне ясно пишется про проблему подключения к БД. И даже написано что логин/пароль не подходят.